# Re-ordering navigation

Tags: navigation

I have very similar situation to

[re-ordering navigation for quick launch section](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/re-ordering-navigation-for-quick-launch-section/13776#13776)

I have about 6 links that is under the quick lunch. I only 3 headings. These 6 links will go under the "Project Management" heading.

The last line node.MoveToLast does not resolve because it wants the whole navcollection. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MoveToLast() requires an SPNodeCollection be passed in as the parent. Fortunately, each node in the QuickLaunch has a Children property which is the node collection that you need.

Please refer to [re-ordering navigation for quick launch section](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/re-ordering-navigation-for-quick-launch-section) for the code sample you can use.

Comment: @Laurie: You ROCK GIRL...... Thanks. I will let you how it went. Thanks a lot..... Robi

Comment: @Hey there: the 6 links under the main navigation did not move to "Project" header area.

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint and stepping into the code to see where it's failing. It could be a spelling error on the heading name or something.

Comment: @Laurie: It goes through all the lines and does not have any hick-ups. I have 3 headings and they are all populated child. However, I have 6 links directly under the main tree (not under any header) and these needs to be moved to project header.

Comment: Could it be that these 6 aspx pages gets added right before calling this function? I tried adding web.update() before running the updateNavigation routine but no help.

Comment: The code sample only looks for nodes that are children of another heading. If the nodes that you want to move are not under a heading, you will need to remove the foreach that goes through the Children.

Comment: kool then just if(header.Title = "abc page title" || etc?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: the first foreach only iterates 3 times (i guess for each header since i have 3 headers) and therefore the code below never runs.

Comment: foreach (SPNavigationNode heading in web.Navigation.QuickLaunch)
            {
                if (heading.Title == strNodeName)
                {
                    moveToHeadingIndex = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    
                        if (heading.Title == "my link 1" ||
                             heading.Title == "product link 2" ||
                             heading.Title == "news link 3" ||

Comment: Do these pages actually exist in the Quick Launch? Is this a publishing site? Because it looks like publishing pages use CurrentNavigationNodes instead of Navigation.QuickLaunch.

Comment: Yes, these are publishing pages sitting inside the pages library. They do appear in the quick lunch. What's the fix then?

Comment: It looks like this link might fix your problem: http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2007/08/manage-publishing-page-nodes-in-site.html